# PyCharm not doing full syntax coloring for a specific file name

Tags: django, pycharm

In my Django projet, I have one models.py file that PyCharm is only partially syntax coloring: it's coloring the Python keywords and comments but not other things it normally does like coloring method names, keyword parameters. This is the only file in my project like this -- all other .py files are fully syntax colored.

It's the file name not contents that is the issue. I know this because when I rename the file, PyCharm immediately fully syntax colors it. When I rename it back to models.py, it goes back to partial coloring.

Note it's not just the syntax coloring that's off -- it's also other code analysis-related tools for this file.

What could be causing PyCharm to be treating this one file differently?

Answer (score 1):

In the PyCharm status bar, there is a "Highlighting level" indicator. Clicking on it allows you to choose the highlighting level between "None", "Syntax" and "Inspections", and the selected value is persisted per file. Please try clicking on it and making sure that the level is set to "Inspections".